# Prove $hg=g(ghg^{-1})$ if $hg \in\ Hg$ and $h\in\ H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove $hg=g(ghg^{-1})$ if $hg \in\ Hg$

This is my work so far:

If $hg \in\ Hg$, then $(hg)^{-1} \in\ Hg$.

$(hg)^{-1} = g^{-1}(h)^{-1} = g^{-1}h^{-1} = g^{-1}h^{-1}(gg^{-1})$.

However, this is as far as I can go. I've tried many different things yet can't get to the desired answer.

Any help is very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you want to say $hg=g(g^{-1}hg)$? What's the context here? Something about normal subgroups?

Comment: It's about proving the left and right cosets agree (ie $gH=Hg$) if $ghg^{-1}\in\ H$

Comment: The implication "$hg\in Hg\implies (hg)^{-1}\in Hg$" is false, in general, because $Hg$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: Your statement as it stands is not true. Maybe useful: $hg \in Hg$ if and only if $h \in H$.

Comment: Sorry about that, I accidentally omitted too much information. But yes $h\in\ H$

Comment: @Sylvia You can't prove a false statement! It's not true, in general, even if you assume $H$ to be normal.

Comment: Instead of deleting the post, consider editing it using the useful comments users have provided. As I noted, if $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for every $h\in H$, and every $g\in G$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Hence you want to show that if $H$ is normal, then $Hg=gH$ for every $g\in G$.